# Insert String at particular line eclipse JDT

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I am new to Eclipse JDT, and am using it currently to identify conditional statements (like IF). I am able to get the line-number and corresponding expression using ASTParser, but I cannot find a way to insert a String before that particular line.

Currently, this is what I am doing

```
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
parser.setSource(source.toCharArray());
parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
final CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);    

cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() {

        public boolean visit(IfStatement node) {
            System.out.println(cu.getLineNumber(node.getStartPosition()) + ": " + node.getExpression().toString());
            return false;
        }
});
```

What I would also like to do is insert a sequence of statements in the source file stored in a String every time it gets here. What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: What does Eclipse have to do with the question? What is the `source` variable?

Comment: `source` is the input code stored as a String. I am using Eclipse and thought it would be relevant.